# How can I dequeue a Plugin Stylesheet?

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, css

I am currently using a Plugin, which has created a Stylesheet within the following directory:  `/wp-content/uploads/plugin-name/css`.

I would like to remove this Plugin's Stylesheet, since it is being called after my Custom Stylesheet, where the Plugin is performing unwanted overrides of the Custom Stylesheet.

Instead, I want to remove the Plugin's Stylesheet; copying only required styles into the Custom Stylesheet.

I tried placing the following into the `functions.php` file, within the Child Theme:

```
<?php
function dequeue_dequeue_plugin_style(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin-css' ); //Name of Style ID.
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_dequeue_plugin_style', 999 );
?>
```

Unfortunately, this did not work.  Is anyone able to see if I have gone wrong with my Code or whether Plugin Styles have priority over all files within a Child Theme etc.

Comment: Please specify which plugin so we can have a look how it enqueues the css file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Just figured that if I take away the `-css`, the code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My error.  All I had to do was knock off the `-css` and it worked.

Working code:

```
<?php
function dequeue_dequeue_plugin_style(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin' ); //Name of Style ID.
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_dequeue_plugin_style', 999 );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it.
For style, you have to follow the following codes-

```
function scp_assets_dequeue() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wpcp-slick' ); // style id
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scp_assets_dequeue', 9999);
```

Similarly for script, you have to try the following code-

```
function scp_assets_dequeue() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wpcp-slick' ); // script id
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scp_assets_dequeue', 9999);
```